# What is causing wp-comments-post.php to redirect to the browser's IP address?

Tags: comments, redirect

I've got a copy of WordPress running that has recently been moved off shared hosting and onto a VPS that I control. While a testing copy of the same site runs correctly on another vhost on the same instance, on the same IP address, after the time when I moved the public site across, the comments form began to redirect visitors back to their own IP address with a `302 Found` in place of the successful `302 Moved Temporarily`.

Running WP 3.4.1, I've tried:

- reinstalling WP from the dashboard, and checked all plugins are up to date
- deactivating all plugins and setting the theme to twenty-eleven
- diffing against the working test installation to check they are the same
- testing from more than one IP, computer and browser

all with no effect to the problem.

**What is causing WordPress to redirect from the form submission back to the browser's ip address?**

Here's a sample request to leave a comment at [http://def-proc.co.uk/b/jwybj](http://www.deferredprocrastination.co.uk/blog/2012/incorrect-redirect-on-comment-submission/):

```
Request URL:./blog/wp-comments-post.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

Form Data

```
author:My Name
email:email@my.mail.box
url:(empty)
comment:Comment contents.
akismet_comment_nonce:(akismet nonce)
submit:Post Comment
comment_post_ID:110
comment_post_ID:110
comment_parent:0
bb2_screener_:(bb2 nonce) (my ip address)
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:243
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 01 Aug 2012 17:34:41 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Location:http://(my ip address)/ 
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: whats your .htaccess?

Comment: …and that's the answer, thank you! 

I'd got a [redirect](http://blogfreakz.com/wordpress-tutorial/reduce-spam-in-wordpress-with-htaccess/) for wp-comments-post.php that required the referrer to be from the development site's url. 

Do you want to change your comment to an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .htaccess for possible redirects to the old ip address.

i'm filling up the response with text because, honestly there's nothing much to say ;)

reference [.htaccess](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F)